# R: Error when stacking multiple raster files

Tags: raster, r

I have a large number of rasters in grid format ("asc"). I created a list of files:

```
files <- list.files("D:/......../EnvironData", pattern='asc',
                    full.names = TRUE)
```

Then I want to stack all files:

```
dataStack <- raster::stack(files)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
>
> Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
>   Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.

All raster files have the same spatial dimension and extent.

Comment: Likely one of your files is invalid somehow. Try lapply(seg_along(files), function(x) {print(x); raster(files[x])}) - the last number printed will be the first bad file (or just the last file).

Comment: @mdsumner Thanks for suggestion. I did not find problem in my files. All are perfect.

Comment: Can you insert the output of the `lapply` call suggested by mdsummer into your question?

Comment: @pat-s I have 54 rasters, I tried if any of two rasters get stacked. Unfortunately none. variables

Comment: Try x = lapply(files, raster); s = raster::stack(x)  check elements of x for dim, extent, projection. Are they all the same?

Comment: raster has some dusty corners, it's expected for something so general. You could use rgdal::readGDAL to read them individually then stack those, and there's another reader for this format in maptools, or maybe sp. The more you can explore and report specifics about the easier to debug.

Comment: I had the same issue, but changed the NA values for -9999, then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me too, but it was because my directory was large. R was unable to find the way, so he gave this answer: Error in .rasterObjectFromFile (x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",: Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (File does not exist)

After I put it in another folder with a smaller path, it worked.